# "Proof" that "ZFC + there exists an inaccessible cardinal" is consistent

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, incompleteness, large-cardinals

I have a proof that this theory is consistent using this theory itself. I want to know what's wrong with this proof:

1. "ZFC + there exists an inaccessible caridnal" proves that "ZFC is consistent".
2. "There exists an inaccessible cardinal" is a statement that is independent from ZFC.
3. Combining 1 and 2, we have "ZFC + there exists an inaccessible cardinal" is consistent.

I'm able to conclude (3) because we proved ZFC is consistent in (1) and also that "There exists an inaccesible" is independent from ZFC. If $X$ is a consistent theory and $P$ is a statement independent from $X$, then both $P+X$ and $P+\neg X$ are consistent theories.

**What's wrong with this proof?**

Comment: I'm inclined to doubt that you have proved (2).  You may have proved that if ZFC is consistent then "there is a inaccessible" is not a theorem of ZFC; but I seriously doubt that you have proved the same for "there is no inaccessible." (By the way I assume you are defining "inaccessible cardinal" in a way that excludes $0$, $1$, $2$, and $\aleph_0$.)

Comment: @bof omg I think I took it for granted that (2) had been proven. But assuming (2) is the same as assuming that "ZFC+Inaccessible exists" is consistent

Comment: I'm not sure (I'm not a logician) but I think the word "independent" is ambiguuous in the sense that some people say "X is independent" to mean that neither X nor its negation is provable, while others will mean that just X is unprovable. You might hear some people say that the continuum hypothesis is "consistent ant independent" as if "independent" is only half the story.

Comment: See the usage note in this Wikipedia article. Maybe this inconsistent usage is what led to your confusion. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(mathematical_logic)

Comment: It's not just that (2) has not been proven. The situation is much worse: we can prove that if ZFC is consistent, then we *can't* prove (2) in ZFC!

Comment: @AlexKruckman I thought a proof of that existed in the larger theory : "ZFC+ there exists inaccessible"

Comment: What is "that" in your latest comment?

Comment: @AlexKruckman  I thought that both (1) and (2) were provable in the theory : "ZFC+inaccessible exists". But that's only true for (1). I think (2) is provable in this theory only if this theory is inconsistent

Comment: That's correct. But ZFC+"there are two inaccessible cardinals" does prove (2)!

Comment: @AlexKruckman and then my proof becomes worthless because then I would just be using a larger theory to prove the consistency of a smaller theory :(